# Java 17 app shows very high RAM usage in docker

Tags: java, docker, garbage-collection

I have a application that during idle times usually only needs 1GB of RAM however when I launch it inside in docker, then it shows much higher RAM usage (5GB) from the outside.
The JVM metric show that I still only use ~1GB of RAM, but the JVM does not really release any RAM it ever claimed.
I cannot reduce the RAM limits (~8GB using MaxRamPercentage), as it needs it during high load, startup, and some special events. I could periodically call `System.gc()` as that frees and releases a lot of memory, but the RAM shoots back up to where it was after a few requests. This claiming of unused RAM wastes a lot of resources and causes OOMs on the server as none of the applications release their memory.

According to this [JEP-346](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/346) the "bug" has been fixed, that caused the garbage collector to not release the memory, but I don't see any improvements.

For testing purposes, I also tried using the `-XX:+UseShenandoahGC` and it releases the memory as expected. But during startup it takes almost all the RAM which causes issues during server/multiple simultaneous application restarts.

**TLDR:** Actually used RAM ~1 GB, claimed RAM ~5 GB, RAM Limit ~8GB.
The default GC does not release enough RAM, without explicitly calling System.gc().
Is the G1 GC the default GC in Java 17? (AFAICT it is)
Are there any parameters required to make the changes from [JEP-346](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/346) work as expected?

Comment: For your use case, I *suggest* you try [GraalVM](https://www.graalvm.org/).

Comment: I would love to, but that requires plenty of changes to make it work and I won't be able to do that short term.

Comment: “*But during startup it takes almost all the RAM which causes issues during server/multiple simultaneous application restarts.*”—this statement matches what you said previously, i.e. “*I cannot reduce the RAM limits…, as it needs it during high load, startup, and some special events.*”, but it’s not clear, how this issue is supposed to be solved. If all applications *really need* this amount of RAM (the reason why you can’t reduce the max limit), and they need it all at the same time, because of “*simultaneous application restarts*” only actual RAM can help. Or prevent *simultaneous* restarts.

Comment: "how this issue is supposed to be solved" -> See TLDR for the actual question. "They need it all at the same time" -> The cluster automatically manages this, but the longer it occupies the RAM, the longer it takes to start all the applications. If you have a suggestion on how to improve the wording feel free to leave a comment or edit the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think [this is similar question to what you are asking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54490373/java-12-gc-jep-346is-behavior-is-particularly-disadvantageous-in-container-env).

As it is pointed in the comments to the question this feature is opt-in and can be enabled using parameters described in the [JEP 346 Documentation](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/346#Description).

Both `-XX:G1PeriodicGCInterval` and `-XX:G1PeriodicGCSystemLoadThreshold` have to be set to a value greater than default 0 for the functionality to work.

Comment: Thanks! The parameters seem to work to a certain extend, the RAM during startup is freed earlier than before, but there still is some leeway to the ShenandoahGC. I'll try with different parameter values.